# Applying for a Schengen visa as a tourist in London

Tags: visas, schengen

I am Indian travelling to UK on tourist visa. I am planning for multiple-entry Schengen visa so I can visit Europe during my stay in UK.

As per France consulate we need to provide confirm air tickets at time of visa. As I am travelling from UK I'll be having valid UK visa and return tickets from London to Paris. Will this work?

Answer (score 1):

Having tickets to and from London is not an issue, the only requirement is being able to leave the Schengen area. The problem is that to apply in the UK, you need to be a resident, as specified on the [embassy's website](http://www.ambafrance-uk.org/How-and-where-to-apply-for-a-visa):

> You must be resident in the UK
>
> Your UK residency must have at least 3 months validity after the intended date of departure from the Schengen area.
>
> As per the decree 2008-1176 of the 13th of November 2008, the French Consulate, London, is not competent in processing visa applications of people not resident in the UK, i.e. holders of ’C-Visit’ visas or of a British visa valid for 6 months or less. People who are not resident in the UK must apply for their Schengen visas at the French Consulate in their country of residence.

If you were a resident of the UK, you wouldn't be expected to return anywhere else. But since you are not a resident, your application will most likely be rejected (i.e. the consulate will decline to examine it; your fee would be refunded and there would be no record of any refusal).

Comment: OP doesn't specifically mention they will apply for Schengen visa from the UK only that travel to Schengen is from the UK. Can they not apply from India and provide appropriate documents?