# I work in the UK on a short-term visa and my wife/daughter are in the UK on a tourist visa. Can we apply for a Schengen visa together in the UK?

Tags: visas, schengen, uk, indian-citizens

I am an Indian national currently working in UK on a [Tier 2 short-term visa](https://www.gov.uk/tier-2-intracompany-transfer-worker-visa/overview). My visa is valid till August 2016. My wife and daughter will be visiting the UK on a tourist visa for 2 months. My questions are:

1. Is it possible for all three of us to get a Schengen visa from within the UK?
2. How long will it take?
3. Should I expect any issues?

Comment: Do you want to ask, is it possible for the three of us to apply together from within the UK?

Comment: yes . i want to ask whether it is possible for all 3 of us to travel + we will have any trouble in getting visa ??

Comment: OK, I have voted to reopen the question.  Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @VinayShetty So edit the question to ask exactly what you have clarified.

Comment: Why do you need a visa for the UK? Aren't you already working there?

Comment: Related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30771/applying-for-a-schengen-visa-as-a-tourist-in-london

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Consulate General of France in London](http://www.ambafrance-uk.org/How-and-where-to-apply-for-a-visa):

> **To apply for a visa from the French Authorities in London:**
>
> - You must hold a valid and recognized passport/ travel document;
> - You must be resident in the UK
> - Your UK residency must have at least 3 months validity after the intended date of departure from the Schengen area.
> - As per the decree 2008-1176 of the 13th of November 2008, the French Consulate, London, **is not competent in processing visa applications
>     of people not resident in the UK, i.e. holders of ’C-Visit’ visas or
>     of a British visa valid for 6 months or less**. People who are not
>     resident in the UK must apply for their Schengen visas at the French
>     Consulate in their country of residence.

So to answer your questions:

1. Only you can apply for a Schengen visa in the UK, since your visa is valid for more than 6 months
2. Your wife and daughter should apply for a visa back at their country of residence.