# Can an Indian citizen with Tier 5 GAE visa (work visa) apply for Schengen Visa from UK?

Tags: visas, schengen, uk, indian-citizens

The duration of the stay is from mid-May to early-August. Schengen visa applied from India require booking details, which we haven't planned. Most of the visits will be during the weekends, we are flexible with the country of 1st entry, from where we need to apply. Is it possible to apply from UK ?

Comment: This might help  http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30771/applying-for-a-schengen-visa-as-a-tourist-in-london?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as long as your residence permit is valid for 3 months beyond August. Relevant quote from the [Czech consulate in London](http://www.mzv.cz/london/en/visa_and_consular_information/visa_information/visa_up_to_90_days.html):

> 3. UK Residence permit (original plus photocopy) valid for at least 3 months beyond the return date of the trip to the Schengen Area.