# Can I apply for a Schengen visa in the UK if I'm a student at a local university?

Tags: visas, schengen, uk

I'm a non-EU citizen (Bolivian) currently studying a PhD in the UK. I'm thinking about having a trip throughout Europe. Does anybody know if I can apply for the Schengen visa within the UK where I'm a legally-established student but not a resident? Do I have to travel to my country of origin in order to apply?

Comment: Why do you think that you are not a resident? For Schengen purposes, you most likely are considered one, especially if you are staying there for more than 6 months (i.e. not a on standard visitor visa).

Comment: You may not be a permanent resident, but if you are doing a PhD you are almost certainly a resident.

Comment: If you really are a visitor, it's more difficult but not necessarily impossible, see http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/48756/can-indians-on-uk-tourist-visa-apply-for-schengen-tourist-visa-in-london and http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30771/applying-for-a-schengen-visa-as-a-tourist-in-london

Comment: You have 'normal residence' if your UK visa was issued for a term greater than 6 months

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as long as you have a UK residency permit valid for additional 3 months. Relevant quote from the [Czech consulate in London](http://www.mzv.cz/london/en/visa_and_consular_information/visa_information/visa_up_to_90_days.html):

> 3. UK Residence permit (original plus photocopy) valid for at least 3 months beyond the return date of the trip to the Schengen Area.